# How to make my app stay on top over fullscreen

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I have an app that I use in fullscreen mode. In that app I press a button to open one of my other apps and when I do I would like that app to appear in front of my fullscreen app.

Currently I'm using this code:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    view.window?.level = .floating
}
```

But that only makes it stay on top of the windows not in fullscreen mode.

Is there a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wants to know the answer to this I set "Application is agent (UIElement)" in the apps info.plist to YES. That seemed to solve the issue.